# Can't install Gulp on node 8.12.0

Tags: node.js, gulp

When I try the `sudo npm install --save-dev gulp` command, it returns this error:

```
npm WARN deprecated gulp-util@3.0.8: gulp-util is deprecated - replace it, following the guidelines at https://medium.com/gulpjs/gulp-util-ca3b1f9f9ac5
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@3.0.11: please upgrade to graceful-fs 4 for compatibility with current and future versions of Node.js
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: please upgrade to graceful-fs 4 for compatibility with current and future versions of Node.js
npm WARN gus@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN gus@1.0.0 No repository field.
```

I've reinstalled gulp (multiple times) and node (& npm) and it still won't work.
What do I do?
(I'm using macOS 10.13.6 and I installed node via homebrew)

Comment: Why are you installing npm modules as superuser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you trying to install with `--save-dev`?
Installing Gulp globally should be done with `--global`

Have you checked their installation guide?
https://gulpjs.org/getting-started.html